# How to run JQuery code in IE 8 Script Debugger?

Tags: javascript, debugging, internet-explorer-8

I am trying to use the IE 8's script debugger to run some JQuery code in the **Console** Tab, but all I get back is

```
{...}
```

For example if I try and do something simple like select an element using a class name, I get back some braces an ellipse.

```
>>$('.someclass')
{...}
```

I usually use Firefox with Firebug, but I need to use IE's tool in this case since the problem is only with IE. In Firebug you can run script statements with no problem, I figured IE 8 would be the same.

Comment: "I figured IE 8 would be the same..." The joke is on you, my friend.

Comment: lol, wishful thinking :)

Answer (score 0):

FireBug Lite. The bookmarklet works fine.
http://getfirebug.com/firebuglite